# Holding different datatypes dynamically in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Lets say I have a table `Person` and I need that a user can add different attributes to him/herself.

User should be able to add a `date`, `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `multiple` values.

Lets say he wants to add:

1. Date of birth
2. Name
3. Heigth
4. Children names

How would I hold this in database?

I have 2 ideas:

1. I can hold all the values as `string` or `varchar` and always parse the value back to original format when used. Multiple values holding like `text1#text2#text3` or similar.
2. Having a table, where there are columns for each : date, string, number and only the one that is needed will be populated and other will stay nulls.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a column for each, because then you can add constraints and add a minimum of data validation, you can search, etc...

Comment: 2nd approach is good in my vision, because, it saves your time from splitting the string from database and parsing it to get the result.

Comment: If user creates a new attribute, how do you know its data type?

Comment: See my comment on my answer below, you could have a description field where the user types away a summary of themselves. Not sure of how you are using this data though, as its near impossible (OK a lot of work and looking at each individual user's description) to work with or do anything useful with this data.

Comment: Kaf I have a dropdown for a user. he will select from these types.

Comment: If user has to select a datatype, second option would be good.

Comment: You can always make it xml and save it into the database and then you can deserialize it when you pull the values out?

Answer (score 0):

Good database design should always be `N:1` (many to one) or `1:1` (one to one), never `1:N` (one to many) or `N:N` (many to many), meaning that if you have multiple related fields of a user, you should make a new table that refers to the user.

Since a user can only have one birth date though, you should keep that as a column to the Users table.

For example, in this case you want children names as the "multiple", assigned to one user.

A simple table for that could look like this:

```
ID int primary key
UserID int references User(ID)
Name varchar
```

That way, you can make multiple children names for one user, while still being able to keep constraints in the database (which helps ensure code correctness if you're interfacing with it through an application!)

Some people will suggest having a table for each of the values, just to avoid nulls. For example, to store their birthdate, you make a table similar to the Children names table above, since you won't have to make a column in the Users table that might be null.

Personally I think using nulls are fine, as they allow you to see if there is a relevant result set without joining (or worse, left joining) an entire table of potentially irrelevant information.

Comment: I do not believe there a difference between `1:N` and `N:1` relationship. It's simply a matter of which side of the fence your are looking from. A user may have many values, but many values belong to one user.

Comment: @Kami You are right, but I'm seeing this from the single table's perspective. You should not have multiple rows in the Users table for the same user, which is what is meant by `N:1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use your second approach. In your table 'Person', have a row for each record that has multiple columns each which holds a single value for you desired fields.

So..

```
tbPerson

ID    | Date Of Birth    | Name    | Height    | Childrens names    | etc...
```

To Create a table...

```
CREATE TABLE tbPerson([ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1), [Date Of Birth] DATE, [Name] VARCHAR(50),     Height INT, [Childrens names] VARCHAR(250))
```

This is the best and easiest way and enables editing 1 field of a persons records simple. In your first approach you will have endless nightmares storing everything a 1 long string.

Comment: I think he does not know what attributes user going to add.

Comment: Then create a few extra columns like, user_field1, user_field2 etc.. as VARCHAR. You will need to know all the attributes they can add, in order to store it somewhere and work with the data. OPTION 2 if you really don't know what attributes the user is going to add, perhaps have a description field of a long length where the user can type whatever they want in a summary. Of course this is near impossible to work with any of the data in this field as it will be a mix of values, and the only person who should be able to edit this is the user, like updating their description and simply saving it.

Comment: @ShaunMorehammeredDenovan using multiple columns for essentially the same thing is conceptually a bad idea. Using a separate table for `user_field#` is better, as it allows you to have as many related fields as you like, or none if there are none.